# Comparison digit through Math calc

Tags: abstract-algebra

I hope that my question is still on topic.

I come from programming language.
I'm trying to optimize a function - in doing this, I'm trying to reduce as much as I can comparison (if then else).

Obviosly, if I can do anything through just (simple) math calculation I can improve alot my code.

The question:

I have a serial number e.g. 123456789
I need to check:

`if (single_digit*2>9)
    then return (single_digit*2)-9
 else
    return single_digit*2`

I'm trying to think in a module (mod - %) operation, but I can't find a right way to perform this (if it's possible).

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `(single_digit*2) % 9`?

Comment: e.g. SingleDigit = 1 so 1*2 = 2 and I want to return 2 ; but SingleDigit = 8 so 8*2=16 and I want to return 16-9=7 - So if SingleDigit is 5,6,7,8,9 I want to subtract 9 to result, else I just want to return result as-is

Comment: This is exactly what my formula does, you wanted such a formula with the % operation (ie. the mod operation in some programming languages). If this is not the case please explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Probably I can't explain myself. I just want to skip all the if-then-else statement. I'd like to have just a single math function that check everything together.
I mean, I'd like to find a function that let skip the comparison of the digit and use just simple math function (you know, for the assemply code it could help alot and reduce calculus) to achieve my solution

Comment: Yes, but **again:** This is exactly what my formula does, assuming you have the % operator available, e.g.
`myfunction(single_digit) {  return (2*single_digit) % 9;}`

Comment: You know? You're pretty much right. I think that I just fool myself. But what about the 9? 9*2=18%9=0 and I want 9 :/

Comment: Depends on you available operation, if you have integer division \ you can code
`myfunction(single_digit) {  return (2*single_digit) % 9 + (single_digit\9)*9;}`

Comment: here we are! If you reply, I can confirm as correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can perform the required operations without "if" statement. The most simplified version of your problem could be

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    2x       & \quad \text{if } x < 5\\
    2x-9  & \quad \text{else} \\
  \end{cases}$$
Where $x \in \{1,2,\dots,9\}$. Now, your statements will be

```
if(single_digit<5)
    return single_digit*2
return (single_digit*2)-9
```

Comment: I know. I would like to avoid this evaluation - Trying to optimize